# Galaxy S3 - do not want emails deleted from server when deleting from Galaxy S3

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have Samsung Galaxy S3, I have AOL, Verizon and gmail emails coming into my phone and when I delete these read emails from the phone, I would like those emails to REMAIN on my email server so I may go back to them later in day.

I have tried looking through all the settings on all the accounts but do not see anywhere where I can retain emails on my pc. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I noticed that my AOL email account disappeared a couple of times and had to connect it again.

Comment: In short: Don't delete your mails if you want them still. That's how email works when you use the IMAP access variant. It shows and alters the state on the server. POP3, the other access protocol is inferior and not for mobile use (no push, deletes all fetched mails by default, data hungry, no sync). BTW, this has nothing to do with Android really, it's the same on any device.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) as your client and after configuring your account long-press it, select `Account settings -> Fetching mail -> When I delete a message` and set it to `Do not delete on server` or `Mark as read on server`, whichever suits you better.